# How to delete an array and reuse the same name for a scalar variable?

Tags: awk

With GNU Awk 5.1.0 the following raises an error:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {tmp[1]; delete tmp; tmp = ""}' --
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: attempt to use array `tmp' in a scalar context
```

Apparently the `delete` statement does not delete the array qualifier of the variable which cannot be recycled as a scalar variable. Is there a way to obtain this?

Comment: re: [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359915), of interest in one of Ed Morton's comments linking to the POSIX standard stating a (variable) name cannot be used for both a scalar and an array; so, it's not that the `delete tmp` is not working but that you can't change `tmp's` datatype (scalar to/from array)

Comment: I'd also argue that if anyone wanted to do this they should rethink the names they're giving their variables as there's a problem if you're trying to give the same name to 1 of something (a scalar) as to many of something (an array) or giving the same name to 2 different types of something.

Comment: Sorry, the question is maybe not well formulated, but it was more about the fact that `delete` does not completely delete, and if there is a way to delete _more_, than about whether it is a good idea or not to use the same name for different types of variables. After all, `awk` is loosely typed, and scalar variables can be used to represent strings or numbers...

Comment: what do you mean by `delete more`? are you thinking of the equivalent of the shell `unset`?

Comment: Yes, that's it, shell `unset` does exactly that.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet :  I usually prefer `split("", arr)` as a way to clear its contents and indices, leaving behind nothing but the bare minimum structure of an array. haven't noticed any speed gains via `delete arr`. …...

Comment: ….`length()` would auto cast to scalar when var type is unknown, so the way I do it ( if I'm unsure whether the optional array was passed or not, and if so, if anything already pre-exists) without being `gawk`-dependent is like `for (x in arr) { break }` - an instant loop exit upon the first item of the iterator - the overhead is minimal at best, it leaves existing arrays as is, while initializing non-existing one to an empty array, i.e. `length(arr) == 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apparently the `delete` statement does not delete the array qualifier of
> the variable which cannot be recycled as a scalar variable.

GNU AWK User's Guide when describing [Delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Delete.html) says that

> **CAUTION:** Deleting all the elements from an array does not change its type; you cannot clear an array and then use the array’s name as a
> scalar (i.e., a regular variable). For example, the following does not
> work:
>
> ```
> a[1] = 3
> delete a
> a = 3
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I always forget that the man page, while very complete, is only a subset of the manual.